# Does not work desktop mode android WebView, why?

Tags: android, url, webview

I am using a `WebView` and I need to access a mobile desktop mode site. But it does not work as expected.

I am using `Android Studio version 3.5`. I attached the below code. Kindly, solve my issue.

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUserAgentString(WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(this));
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Client());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    // webView.loadUrl("http://35.154.11.144"); //CMS URL
    webView.loadUrl("https://erp.vvsugars.com/web/login");// VMS URL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the user agent..
You can set a custom user agent if you want.

But if you want to set the correct user agent taken from device itself, then use below code.

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
String userAgent = String.format("%s [%s/%s]", webSettings.getUserAgentString(), "App Android", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Edit:

Starting from API level 17 there is a static method in WebSettings which returns the default User-Agent string used by a WebView:

WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context)

Since the method is static you don't need a WebView instance to run it.

So the code should be,

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString(WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(context));
```

For context if you are in a activity try like this,

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString(WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(this));
```

And remember to put that line after you instantiated webSettings..

If you want to use below api level use a custom user agent string.. Below is an example.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-gb; Nexus One Build/FRF50)AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Put above string inside setUserAgentString method..

Or if you want an easy fix use below.

```
webSettings.setUserAgentString("Android");
```

[Use a user agent string from official chrome website here. Go to the android webview part](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent)

**Good Luck **

Update....
Okay I thought you want android mode.
But you wanted desktop mode..
Use the below core. It will work.

```
String newUA= "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";
```

mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

Edit.. I have updated the above user string. Please use it and try again.. It still doesn't work then use the below code without setting up the user agent string..

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1); webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false); webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204112/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-ten-does-not-work-desktop-mode-android-webview-why).